# from a share point portal website, how can i tell what version of share point is running?

Tags: sharepoint

that is to say if i am browsing around on share point where can i get to a details page to tell me what version of share point it is?

Comment: Do you mean version as 2007/1000 or WSS/MOSS or exact version?

Comment: I want to hit some settings or help page that will tell me what version of share point is running. 2010, 2007, 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're running 2007 and can select "Site Settings" (or "Modify All Site Settings"), it's right there on the newly-opened page to the right of "Version". From there, a pretty up-to-date mapping of version to SP/CU install can be found [here](http://www.sharepointdesignerstepbystep.com/Blog/Articles/How%20To%20find%20the%20SharePoint%20version.aspx).

(edited to reflect Ryan's comment)